# Rvest output returning "Character(0)" instead of the column highlighted with selectorgadget

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape some columns from the Gates Foundation Awarded Grants Table using rvest. Below is my code:

```
library(rvest)    
data1 <- html('http://www.gatesfoundation.org/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database#q/program=US%20Program&year=2015')
table1 <- data1 %>%html_nodes('td:nth-child(5) , td:nth-child(3)') %>% html_text()
table1
```

The output I receive from the "table1" command is the following:

> character(0)

Is there a problem with the css selectors I'm using? Is this type of table not compatible with rvest?

Comment: Which data do you want to obtain from that site?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample code for last two columns using RSelenium (you need to have phantomjs driver in your working directory for the following code to run). See [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-headless.html) for details:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

pJS <- phantom()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs")
remDr$open(silent = FALSE)
remDr$navigate("http://www.gatesfoundation.org/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database#q/program=US%20Program&year=2015")

test.html <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) #html is deprecated in new version of rvest
test.text<-test.html%>%
  html_nodes("td:nth-child(5) , td:nth-child(3)")%>%
  html_text()
test.df<-data.frame(matrix(test.text,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))
names(test.df)<-c("program","amount")
remDr$close()
pJS$stop()

df

test.df
program     amount
1     Postsecondary Success   $498,727
2          Community Grants   $200,000
3  Global Policy & Advocacy $1,035,523
4     Postsecondary Success    $95,000
5     Postsecondary Success    $25,000
6             College-Ready $1,257,526
7             College-Ready $1,066,403
8    Strategic Partnerships    $50,000
9             College-Ready $1,195,581
10            College-Ready   $300,000
11            College-Ready   $100,000
12            College-Ready    $21,200
```